# Как сделать так ,чтобы кнопка открывала новое окно и закрывала текущее?

Tags: python, tkinter, окно

**У меня есть кнопка "btn_open_dialog" которая открывает дочернее окно Child.Как можно сделать так,чтобы при этом она закрывала текущее окно Main?**

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.constants import CENTER, NW, W
from tkinter.font import BOLD
import pip
from plyer import notification


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()

    def init_main(self):
        toolbar=tk.Frame(bg="white",bd=2)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.X)
        self.add_img=tk.PhotoImage(file="23.gif")
        self.add_img2=tk.PhotoImage(file="36.gif")
        btn_open_dialog=tk.Button(toolbar,text="Создать напоминание-уведомление",command=self.cb,bg="white",bd=1,compound=tk.TOP,image=self.add_img)
        btn_open_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
       
    
    def cb(self):
        Child()
        
   

class Child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_child()

    def init_child(self):
        self.title("Создать напоминание-уведомление")
        self.geometry("800x600")
        self.config(bg="#CCFFFF")

        label_title=tk.Label(self,text="Введите название",bg="#CCFFFF")
        label_title.place(x=100,y=10)
        label_entry=tk.Label(self,text="Введите текст",bg="#CCFFFF")
        label_entry.place(x=100,y=80)
        

        entry_title=ttk.Entry(self)
        entry_title.place(x=200,y=10)
        entry_message=ttk.Entry(self)
        entry_message.place(x=200,y=80)
        

        btn_make_noti=tk.Button(self,text="Создать уведомление",command=lambda:self.make_noti(entry_title,entry_message))
        btn_make_noti.place(x=200,y=150)

    def make_noti(self,entry_title,entry_message,):
        notification.notify(title=entry_title.get(),
        message= entry_message.get(),
        app_icon ="icon.ico",
        timeout=15,
        toast=False)



if __name__=="__main__" :
    root =tk.Tk()
    app=Main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.title("Reminder app")
    root.config(bg="#CCFFFF")
    root.geometry("800x600")
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы убрать (спрятать) окно с экрана, но при этом не уничтожать (что актуально для главного окна, т.к. при его уничтожении приложение завершит свою работу), надо использовать метод [`withdraw()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.withdraw-method) этого окна. Например:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
```

Чтобы снова вернуть видимость этому окну используйте метод [`deiconify()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.deiconify-method) (или `wm_deiconify()`).

```
root.deiconify()
```

Если окно больше не нужно, то вызовите метод [`destroy()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.destroy-method). Это уничтожит окно со всеми принадлежащими ему виджетами. Учтите, что уничтожение главного окна приведёт к завершению приложения.

```
root.destroy()
```

Соответственно, в вашем случае вам при открытии дочернего окна надо спрятать главное окно. А при закрытии дочернего окна либо вернуть главное окно (иначе процесс останется, но ни одного окна у него не будет, так что придётся убивать процесс через Диспетчер задач, или командой *kill*). Либо уничтожить главное окно, чтобы выйти из программы.

Ну и код *(см. комментарии в нём)*:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from plyer import notification


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.root = root        # << сохраняем ссылку на главное окно
        self.init_main()

    def init_main(self):
        toolbar=tk.Frame(self.root, bg="white", bd=2)  # << Frame порождаем от главного окна
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.add_img  = tk.PhotoImage(file="23.gif")
        self.add_img2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="36.gif")
        btn_open_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Создать напоминание-уведомление", 
                                    command=self.cb, bg="white", bd=1, compound=tk.TOP,
                                    image=self.add_img)
        btn_open_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    
    def cb(self):
        Child(self.root)  # << передаём ссылку на главное окно


class Child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent  # << сохраняем ссылку на родительское окно
        self.init_child()
        # vv перехватываем кнопку закрытия окна чтобы вернуть назад родительское окно
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: (parent.deiconify(), self.destroy()))
        parent.withdraw()  # << прячем родительское окно
        
    def init_child(self):
        self.title("Создать напоминание-уведомление")
        self.geometry("800x600")
        self.config(bg="#CCFFFF")

        label_title = tk.Label(self, text="Введите название", bg="#CCFFFF")
        label_title.place(x=100, y=10)
        label_entry = tk.Label(self, text="Введите текст", bg="#CCFFFF")
        label_entry.place(x=100, y=80)

        entry_title = ttk.Entry(self)
        entry_title.place(x=200, y=10)
        entry_message = ttk.Entry(self)
        entry_message.place(x=200, y=80)

        btn_make_noti = tk.Button(self, text="Создать уведомление", 
                                  command=lambda:self.make_noti(entry_title,entry_message))
        btn_make_noti.place(x=200,y=150)

    def make_noti(self,entry_title,entry_message,):
        notification.notify(title=entry_title.get(),
                            message=entry_message.get(),
                            app_icon ="icon.ico",
                            timeout=15,
                            toast=False)


if __name__=="__main__" :
    root =tk.Tk()
    app=Main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.title("Reminder app")
    root.config(bg="#CCFFFF")
    root.geometry("800x600")
    root.mainloop()
```